# .NET Request.Browser incorrectly identifies Opera version

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, browser, opera

The following code in .Net MVC 3 returns "Opera 9" when it Should return "Opera 12", or "Opera 11"  Have confirmed this on multiple machines, Win 7 64 bit and XP 32 bit.

```
public ActionResult TestBrowser()
{
    return Content(Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.MajorVersion);
}
```

For some reason there is a 9.8 in the browser tag for Opera, and the actual version number is at the end.
[image: Opera Help...About]

Is this Opera's fault for formatting the browser tag wrong, or the **HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase** class's fault for parsing it wrong?

Comment: User-agents are easily spoofed and inaccurate. Maybe you should look into feature detection instead. But I can confirm that it returns Opera 9 for me too.

Comment: What is `Request.Browser.MinorVersion` returning?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth MinorVersion is returning 80

Comment: @NeilN: Hm. At least it seems to be an accepted practice to have such a split version. Firefox does the same. Mozilla/5.0 at the beginning and the actual Firefox version at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I found this explaining the user-agent string for Opera and why Opera/9.80 is now hard coded inside the user-agent string.

http://my.opera.com/community/openweb/idopera/

Like I said in my comment, it might be better to look at feature detection since you might have the same problem with IE 10 soon.

EDIT: One solution might be to parse the user-agent string yourself.

EDIT 2: If you would like go with browser detection, there is the Modernizr Javascript library (http://modernizr.com/) which does a wonderful job.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the correct versioning (assuming it isn't a spoofed user-agent string) is always the version shown after the last slash. So remove everything in front of and including the last slash and the remainder will be your current version.

Answer (score 1):

@Sashenka: The hard portion of the Opera string is needed as you pointed out. I would not be surprised if a similar thought isn't needed for other browsers for similar reasons. However, feature detection is just another can of worms waiting to byte you in the beehind. For example, every release of IE alone changes the way they process things; i.e., you can't trust M$ at all. Parsing the user-agent string isn't all that difficult and nearly guarantees success. All that said, I wonder if it isn't easier to write code to the standards, include IE bandages as required, and let each browser present the page as their designers had intended; good, bad or indifferent! :-)

Comment: The problem is Opera said "Opera/9.80 is hard coded at the beginning of the user agent string because of broken browser sniffing scripts which detect “Opera/10” and above as Opera 1" So now we have hacks to fix broken dependencies, which create more broken dependencies.  It is now a circular problem :(

Comment: I still think feature detection might be more future-proof than browser detection. If MS break something with a release of IE or a hotfix, you will still detect the same version of IE but without the feature you were accustomed to. There is also the Modernizr javascript library (http://modernizr.com/) which help you easily detect what is supported by the browser visiting your website.